Unable to Move Files Across Server using SFTP Bitvise via Batch Script
I am trying setup a task scheduler job to move files from server A location D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST to server B and archive files on server A to D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST path.
Following are the settings done while new task is created.

In start a program window path to batch file is provided as follows:
"D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\NEW_SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD.bat"


Arguments are defined as:
SPANIST D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST >D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\LOGS\SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD_Detail_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%.log '



Following is the code used in batch file which fails at sftpc step. I have checked the user and password in Bitvise and it's working fine. Also, this code when ran step by step authenticates successfully but fails to move files to Server B.
set "Pattern=%~1"
set "Src_Path=%~2" 
set "Arc_Path=%~3"

set "CurrentDate=" & for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do if not defined CurrentDate set "CurrentDate=%%G%%H%%I" & set "CurrentTime=%%J%%K%%L"

set "LogFileName=D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\SFTP_%Pattern%_TO_EMDAD_%CurrentDate%CurrentTime%"

echo %DATE% %TIME% Starting process
echo %DATE% %TIME% Changing directory to "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%">"%LogFileName%"
pushd "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" || (echo Failed!>>"%LogFileName%" & popd & exit /B 1)

echo %DATE% %TIME% Starting transfer (copy/sftp)>>"%LogFileName%" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client\sftpc.exe" prod_emdad_spanist@10.2.173.3 -pw=Emdad123 -cmd="put %Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%\%Pattern%*"


if not errorlevel 1 goto ARCH

echo %DATE% %TIME% ERROR: Issue in transferring the files to ETL server>>"%LogFileName%"

:ARCH
move "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" "%Arc_Path%\"

if  not errorlevel 1 goto NEXT
echo %DATE% %TIME% ERROR: Error in archiving files!>>"%LogFileName%"
popd & exit /B 1

:NEXT  
echo "%DATE% %TIME% Files transferred and archived successfully.>"%LogFileName%"

popd & endloca

XML of the task scheduler job is below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2024-07-08T18:11:59.5154495</Date>
    <Author>SJN\emdadetprd</Author>
    <URI>\NEW_PROD_EMDAD_SPANIST_SFTP</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2024-07-08T16:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-3895855529-3008202435-1737094514-1599</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\NEW_SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD.bat"</Command>
      <Arguments>SPANIST D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST\DAT D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>


@Compo Fourth one is the output location of log file.

My point is that >D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\LOGS\SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD_Detail_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%.log isn't used, so why include it? Also it seems to 'pointlessly' include the leading stdOut redirection operator. Also what about the fifth argument '?

@Compo There is no fifth argument. So you mean to remove > operator right? One more thing when this task is run in task scheduler it says 0x1 when it is run with highest privilege's but on cmd it error out.

I am quite capable of reading what you submitted as arguments! %1=SPANIST, %2=D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST, %3=D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST, %4=>D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\LOGS\SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD_Detail_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%.log, %5='.

You are right about the arguments. I have used LogFileName inside the batch script so we don't need to add it as parameter. Also, removed parameter #5.

So, how does that affect the scheduled task? Please update your question body, code, and results as necessary.

I suggest a modification of the batch file to:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "Pattern=%~1"
set "Src_Path=%~2"
set "Arc_Path=%~3"

set "CurrentDate=" & for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do if not defined CurrentDate set "CurrentDate=%%G%%H%%I" & set "CurrentTime=%%J%%K%%L"
set "LogFileName=D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\SFTP_%Pattern%_TO_EMDAD_%CurrentDate%%CurrentTime%.txt"

echo %DATE% %TIME% Starting process
echo %DATE% %TIME% Changing directory to "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%">"%LogFileName%"
pushd "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" 2>nul || (echo Failed!>>"%LogFileName%" & exit /B 1)

echo %DATE% %TIME% Starting transfer (copy/sftp)>>"%LogFileName%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client\sftpc.exe" prod_emdad_spanist@10.2.173.3 -pw=Emdad123 -cmd="put %Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%\%Pattern%*"
if not errorlevel 1 goto ARCH

echo %DATE% %TIME% ERROR: Issue in transferring the files to ETL server!>>"%LogFileName%"

:ARCH
popd
move "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" "%Arc_Path%\" >nul 2>nul
if  not errorlevel 1 goto NEXT
echo %DATE% %TIME% ERROR: Error in archiving files!>>"%LogFileName%"
exit /B 1

:NEXT
echo "%DATE% %TIME% Files transferred and archived successfully.>>"%LogFileName%"
endlocal

A small mistake is on the line which defines the log file name. There is a % missing after %CurrentDate before %CurrentTime% or after %CurrentDate% before CurrentTime%. That was my mistake as I posted this command line wrong in a comment which has been deleted in the meantime.
Another small mistake is & popd on the line with pushd. The conditional command operator || results in the execution of the command line defined inside the command block beginning with ( and ending with ) on the same line if pushd exited with 1 indicating an error on making the specified directory the current working directory for cmd.exe processing the batch file. popd cannot pop a directory path from stack in this case as pushd has not pushed the current working directory as defined with scheduled task element WorkingDirectory (scheduled task property Start in) on the stack on failure. See also single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file explaining the unconditional command operator & and the conditional command operator ||.
If the directory does not exist, pushd outputs the following error message to handle STDERR:
The system cannot find the path specified.

That error message on directory not existing is of no interest because of the error is documented with Failed! in the log file after the line which is written before into the log file with the full directory name. The command line with pushd contains for that reason now 2>nul to redirect the error message output by pushd in case of an error to the device NUL for suppressing it.
The main problem to fix is the line:
move "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" "%Arc_Path%\"

That command line tries to move the entire directory D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST\DAT\20240729 to the directory D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST which fails with the error message:
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The process using this directory is cmd.exe currently processing the batch file because of making this directory the current directory with the pushd command line.
The solution is inserting below :ARCH the line with the command popd to restore the initial current directory as defined in scheduled task with WorkingDirectory (property Start in). Then the command move can move the entire directory to the directory specified as last argument of the command line executed by the Task Scheduler.
There is used as next line:
move "%Src_Path%\%CurrentDate%" "%Arc_Path%\" >nul 2>nul

>nul 2>nul is appended as command move outputs on success the message:
1 dir(s) moved.

That success message is of no interest.
A possible error message on another process has opened a file in that directory or any subdirectory or is using that directory or a subdirectory as current working directory is also suppressed by redirecting it to device NUL.
The log file is updated with either a success or an error message depending on exit code of command move.
The line popd & exit /B 1 is modified now to just exit /B 1 because of popd was executed already before in any use case. The last line is modified to just endlocal for the same reason (with missing l at the end).
I suggest further changing in scheduled task the property Program/script, i. e. Command in the XML export, from
"D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\NEW_SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD.bat"

to
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe

and the Arguments to:
/D /C D:\EMDAD\SFTP_Scripts\SPANIST\NEW_SFTP_SPANIST_TO_EMDAD.bat SPANIST D:\SFTP_Jump_Location\SPANIST\DAT D:\EMDAD\ETL_SERVER_SFTP_TRANSFER_ARCHIVE\SPANIST

That is the nearly the command line which is really executed by the Windows Task Scheduler with exception of option /D.
A batch file is not an executable. There is built-in in Windows that the execution of a file with file extension .bat or .cmd results in execution of %ComSpec% /C with the batch file name and its arguments appended. The system environment variable ComSpec is defined with %SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe. The environment variable ComSpec can be redefined in the system environment variables list although that is a very bad idea and most often causes lots of troubles on doing it.
It is a bit more efficient specifying directly the Windows Command Processor executable as Command and its options /D (must be always left to /C or /K) and /C (run command line and close in comparison to /K for run command line and keep running) and next the batch file name and its arguments in properties of scheduled task. The usage of option /D makes the scheduled task more fail safe because of the AutoRun registry string value of the Command Processor is ignored and not executed first if existing which is not the case by Windows default. There are much too many people adding an AutoRun registry string value for executing a batch file to add and change environment variables for a specific execution environment without knowing how harmful that batch file execution is for all other processes (programs, scheduled tasks, services). The usage of option /D makes the cmd.exe execution by this scheduled task independent on any AutoRun registry string value.
It would be also good changing the file extension from .bat to .cmd. A Windows batch file interpreted by cmd.exe should have since Windows NT 4.0 the file extension .cmd. The file extension .bat is still supported by Windows and cmd.exe for compatibility with batch files written for interpretation by COMMAND.COM of MS-DOS and Windows 95/98/ME, but it is better using .cmd as file extension for newly written Windows batch files although the differences on execution of a .bat and a .cmd file are very small and most often do not matter.
